# Can any one help me how to use dojo framework of ajax in my my struts2 application

Tags: java, ajax, dojo, struts2

I want to change the content of a select box when the values in another select box changes.
Please tell me how to use dojo. How to call the struts 2 action & get the result through ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with struts2-core there comes a tag  but this does not work with ajax.

The struts2 dojo tag is marked as deprecated so it is better not to use it in a new project.

In the Wiki for the [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery) is a example for an [AJAX based Double Select](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/SelectTag#A_simple_Doubleselect_with_Topics), maybe this is an option for you.